# Where does the formula for solving exact differential equations come from?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My professor put this formula in the lecture notes for solving exact differential equations:

$$
\int_{x_0}^x M(x, y)dx + \int^y_{y_0}N(x_0, y)dy = C
$$

He also says that we usually put $x_0 \text{ and } y_0 = 0$. But I don't understand where it comes from or why does it work.

Comment: solving what differential equation ?

Comment: An exact differential equation. One that is in the form
$$
M(x, y)dx+N(x, y)dy=0
$$
Where ${\partial M \over \partial y} = {\partial N \over \partial x}$

Comment: What if you put $x_1$ instead of $x_0$, can you rewrite this integral in terms of the formula above?

Comment: He solved one using $x_0 = 1$ and he still got the answer. I'm asking because I don't know the derivation of it and the intuition behind _why it works_.

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud I upvoted your question but you should probably edit the question a bit because there are close votes. For instance including the differential equation this solves. And maybe some more background. Welcome at MSE !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works because the [Poincare lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_lemma) ensures that there is a function $P$ such that
$$\tag{1}
{M\choose N}=\nabla P\,.
$$
Let $\gamma$ be a curve connecting $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x,y)\,:$
$$
\gamma:t\mapsto \cases{
{x_0+t(x-x_0)\choose y_0}\,,&$t\in [0,1]\,,$\\[2mm]
{x\choose y_0+(t-1)(y-y_0)}\,,&$t\in[1,2]\,.$
}
$$
Then, calculating the line integral,
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
0&=\int_\gamma M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy\\&=\int_0^2M\Big(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t)\Big)\dot\gamma_1(t)+N\Big(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t)\Big)\dot\gamma_2(t)\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1M\Big(x_0+t(x-x_0),y_0\Big)(x-x_0)\,dt\\&~+\int_1^2N\Big(x,y_0+(t-1)(y-y_0)\Big)(y-y_0)\,dt\\
&\stackrel{\text{chg. of var.}}{=}\int_{x_0}^x M(x, y_0)\,dx + \int^y_{y_0}N(x, y)\,dy\\&\stackrel{(1)}{=}
\int_{x_0}^x \partial_x P(x, y_0)\,dx + \int^y_{y_0}\partial_y P(x, y)\,dy\\[2mm]
&=\cancel{P(x,y_0)}-P(x_0,y_0)+P(x,y)-\cancel{P(x,y_0)}\,.\tag{2}
\end{align}
Equation (2) is in short
$$
P(x,y)=P(x_0,y_0)
$$
which defines the solution $y$ to the ODE
$$
M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy
$$
as an implicit function.

Comment: Nice answer +1!

Comment: @mick Thanks. We are all standing on the shoulders of giants, such as Poincare and Chuck Norris. :)