# How should I integrate total differential correctly $dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

let say we have $z(x,y)$, and $x(t), y(t)$

From total differential we have $$dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy$$

Then we differentiate it with respect to $t$:

$$\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Then I integral both sides with respect to $t$ again

$$\int\frac{dz}{dt}dt=\int\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}dt+\int\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}dt$$

$$\int dz=\int\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\int\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy=z$$

From the last line, I notice this is incorrect because we cannot integrate w.r.t different variables at the same time, but from the last equation, I integrate with $t$ on both sides, and this should be fine, so I don't see where it went wrong.

From the second equation, $\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$, how do I recover $z$ correctly?

---

I read this, the last post but I don't see how to from $df=xdy+ydx$ to $\int\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy=\int xdy+\int y\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}dy$  [How to integrate a total derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537262/how-to-integrate-a-total-derivative)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does the formula for solving exact differential equations come from?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4682927/where-does-the-formula-for-solving-exact-differential-equations-come-from)

Comment: @KurtG. No need to rush to close my question. You just answered that an hour ago. I do not really understand your post.

Comment: What domain (in this case, what 2D curve) are you integrating over? You cannot just write "$\int$".

Comment: When approaching such questions it is not helpful to manipulate expressions involving differentials as if a notation takes care of everything. Saying you don't understand my post is also not very helpful. Happy to give further explanations when you specifically tell me what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: @MishaLavrov  some indefinite integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @KurtG. I am still reading the wiki you referred to. Your post content is so new to me, like fresh new. If you are happy to, would you please look at the link I provided and explain that why it is the case?

Comment: @LJNG [The last answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2538174) to the question you linked to explains why an "indefinite integral over $\mathbb R^2$" is not a thing. We cannot take antiderivatives of arbitrary $1$-forms.

Comment: I looked at the link. If you really want to get to the bottom of this I recommend to study line integrals in $\mathbb R^2$ patiently and what the conditions are that make them independent of the curve chosen. This will lay the foundation for many things to come in physics and differential geometry. Manipulating "indefinite" integrals like you do (and some in the link you provided) is not the right way to go.

Comment: @MishaLavrov My bad. Probably we have the different ordered posts? I should've said the highest thumb-up post